# Загрузка .ui при инициализации класса QMainWindow в PySide6

Tags: python, python-3.x, ui, pyside6, qmainwindow

Мне нужно загрузить документ **`.ui`** при инициализации `QMainWindow`, то что я откопал в интернете, это

```
ui_file = QFile("mainwindow.ui")
ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)

loader = QUiLoader()
window = loader.load(ui_file)
window.show()
```

но это делается из вне, а мне нужно, что-то типа:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.loadUi("mainwindow.ui")

    #...#...

main = MainWindow()
main.show()
```

Comment: Смотрим здесь  https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtUiTools/loadUiType.html#loaduitype и читаем здесь https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtUiTools/loadUiType.html#loaduitype

Comment: За ответ спасибо, но вот [здесь](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtUiTools/loadUiType.html#loaduitype) в примере, окно создается с помощью `loadUiType` вне класса, а мне хотелось узнать, можно ли внутри класса `QMainWindow` загрузить `.ui` файл в класс, чтобы далее обращаться к нему с помощью self

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу проверить как это сделать в *PySide6*.

Могу лишь предложить попробовать так:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtUiTools import loadUiType


generated_class, base_class = loadUiType("themewidget.ui")
# the values will be:
#  (<class '__main__.Ui_ThemeWidgetForm'>, <class 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget'>)

class MyApp(base_class, generated_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        generated_class.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ладно, я так понял у `QMainWindow` в `PySide6` нет метода для загрузки `.ui`, спасибо за старание

Comment: @Mr.123 в документации пишут: ... Мы рекомендуем не использовать этот подход (loadUiType(uifile: str)), поскольку рабочий процесс должен заключаться в создании файла Python из файла .ui, а затем его импорте и загрузке для использования!

Comment: Ладно, воспользуюсь все таки `QUiLoader()`, насчет него вроде бы ничего не говорят;

Answer (score 0):

В итоге...

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load('ui/MainWindow.ui')
        # ....

    def show(self):
        self.ui.show()
```